# Cordova web server with configurable responses

Tags: javascript, cordova, http

Is there any way to set up a local web server in a Cordova application such that I can control the responses via Javascript?  I'm currently developing a custom plugin that communicates with a remote system via HTTP.  I'd like to be able to run integration tests on this that are written in the Javascript code of a Cordova application, so I can easily test them in all supported platforms (Android, iOS, and ideally in the browser too... although the latter seems a little unlikely to be possible), but this means I need to be able to set up mock API responses from javascript code ... which will require the presence of a mock server that the plugin can communicate with.

I'm familiar with [this plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd), but it can only respond using files in the local system -- I want to be able to generate responses and capture sent POST data in a Javascript callback.  Is there any existing way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having searched extensively, I came to the conclusion that no such plugin exists.
I have therefore started an implementation of such a plugin myself: the initial version is now available on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-httpserver-dynamic) and [GitHub](https://github.com/jh3141/cordova-plugin-httpserver-dynamic), with a sample project available in the github repository.

Android support is currently functioning, and I intended to start on iOS support in the next few days.

(Updated to add: unfortunately the project I was working on was cancelled, so have not had time supported by my employer to finish the iOS version, and as I don't have a mac personally so can't work on this on my own time, this seems unlikely to happen in the near future, but if anyone else needs it, it should be relatively simple to add the iOS version)